# If there is no lat/lng valu, then don't plot it on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, error-handling

I've got a working page that successfully plots markers on a map after calling my own API (which is a restaurant DB on MongoDB Atlas). E.g. If I search for 'Fleetwood' it will plot all restaurants in Fleetwood on the map.

However, it breaks if I search for a location that lacks lat/lng number values. My restaurant DB has 500K+ locations and lots of places don't have lat/lngs.

EDIT:
I've tried to adjust my code so as not to push markers to my array if they don't have lat/lng values (but my attempts have failed).
Here is one of my attempts. I try to use an IF statement to say, if data[i].Geocode_Latitude is not null, then assign it to a variable. But the error is get is:
ReferenceError: pot is not defined
at getTown (index_try7_test.html:99)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Javascript Calling APIs</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=INSERT_GOOGLE_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async defer></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
      margin: auto;
      height: 750px;
      width: 75%;
    }

    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
  <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue(); deleteOverlays()">Get Value</button>


  <button type="button" onclick="reset();">Reset</button>


  <script>
    function deleteOverlays() {
      if (markersArray) {
        for (i in markersArray) {
          markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markersArray.length = 0;
      }
    }

    function reset() {
      map.setZoom(6);
      deleteOverlays();
    };

    var markersArray = [];
    console.log(markersArray);

    function getInputValue() {
      var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("x-rapidapi-key", "169034d4a5msha6f68db3ab64e43p12abf2jsnabff656340a7");

      var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
      };

      var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("x-rapidapi-key", "169034d4a5msha6f68db3ab64e43p12abf2jsnabff656340a7");
      const api_url = 'https://wyre-data.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/town'
      var town = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
      };

      async function getTown() {

        const response = await fetch(api_url + '/' + town, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
        //console.log(data);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          let la = data[i].Geocode_Latitude;
          let lo = data[i].Geocode_Longitude;

if (data[i].Geocode_Latitude !== null) {
  let pot = {
    lat: la,
    lng: lo
  };
}

          let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pot,
            map: map,
            icon: 'pin.png'
          });

// if (marker.position.lat !== null) { markersArray.push(marker) };

          markersArray.push(marker);
          //console.log(pot);
          //console.log([i]);
          console.log(markersArray);

          bounds.extend(marker.position);
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(data[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        };


        /* Zoom to all markers found, centre on them and fit to map boundary */
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

      }

      getTown();

    }

    let map;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: {
          lat: 54.9421859,
          lng: -2.7433701
        },
        zoom: 6,
      });
    }
  </script>

  <h2>The End...</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"I thought it more useful to show my working code"_ - That doesn't help at all and is not the scope of SO. Please add your attempt(s), any error messages this produces and what you've tried to solve those -> [mcve]

Comment: But this shouldn't be anything more than a simple `if (...) { markersArray.push(...) }`

Comment: @Andreas ive edited my post to show you some of the things ive tried, along with errors. Im a beginner so this may well be a very basic problem to solve. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think "undefined" values will be `null`? -> `console.log(data[i].Geocode_Latitude)`

Comment: Thanks Andreas, i assumed null was the same as undefined - now i know they are different. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking to see if it exists to create the variable, bu you continue with the rest of the logic. You should be skipping it.

So instead of

```
if (data[i].Geocode_Latitude !== null) {
  let pot = {
    lat: la,
    lng: lo
  };
}
```

move to the next iteration

```
for(...) {
  let la = data[i].Geocode_Latitude;
  let lo = data[i].Geocode_Longitude;
  if (la === null) { continue; }
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it Epascarello! @Andreas i changed from using 'null' to 'undefined' and this made it work for me. I made the wrong assumption that null was the same as undefined, thanks.

Comment: The comparison has to be with `undefined` because the properties are missing completely in the response.